# Verbosity level in simple Logger implemenation C++

Tags: c++, logging, verbosity

Im currently implementing a simple Logger for a project due my studies in C++.

I already got a Logger base class, as some different appenders and the next step is to implement verbosity levels.
The problem is that I´m not sure if i understood the concept of verbosity levels correctly and so I wanted to get some feebback before I start to implement them.
So from my understanding a verbosity level in general works as following:

User creates two Logger first:
f.e.:

```
FileLogger fl; 
VSLogger vl;
```

afterwards he can set the verbosity level like:

```
fl.setLoggerLevel(DEBUG);
vl.setLoggerLevel(FATAL_ERROR);
```

afterwards he can logg as he wants, like:

```
fl.logg("New Object of Type .... created");
ASSERT(1,2, "1==2");
```

while assert writes into the VSLogger with fatal error level

and in the Ouput file it would probably look like this:

```
13:36 Msg: New Object of Type .... created (LEVEL:DEBUG);
```

and in Visual Studio it would probably look like this:

```
13:36 Msg: Assert (1==2) failed (LEVEL:FATAL_ERROR)
```

Is that the sence of a verbosity level or have i missunderstood the concepts of verbosity level in general?

Comment: Verbosity normally tells *how much* your logger actually logs. What you are describing here are log *levels*. And normally you got one logger, specify the log level on a per-log basis and can set which log levels actually get logged.

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I understand your point (I actually found almost the same definition on some other sites while researching) but what i don´t understand is following: The Logger cannot logg things himself (at least if it´s not hardcoded in some way). So the user always has to call the logg function if he wants to logg something and provides a log level with it. So how can the logger differentiate between what he logs and what not? Do i have to say just log things that are at least ERROR level? If so, why would i even log things related to INFO level than, if the logger never logs them?

Comment: You call `logger.verbosity(INFO | WARNING | DEBUG);` for example, and only those three levels get actually logged, you just have to check against the verbosity flag in your `log` function: `void log(unsigned level, char const* msg){ if(!(verbosity_flag & level)) return; /* else log it */ }`

Comment: Ah oke now i get it. Thank you. I will try to implement everything first now and may come back with the code in a few days if there is still something unclear or I think something probably could be done better

Comment: @Xeo: I would avoid using a mask for verbosity levels. The common implementation in loggers is that each log level *includes* the higher levels. That is, if you set the log level to `INFO` you are automatically expecting to see any `WARN`and `ERROR` messages, but not `DEBUG`, and that in turn is usually implemented by having the levels mapped to numbers and comparing: `if (log_level >= msg_level ) return;` (if we are configured to log `WARN` (say 2) and get a message of level `INFO` (say 3), then do not log)

Comment: @David: That may be common, but I'd rather support both ways (by defining "groups" of warnings), than only support one. I used a logger that allowed you to enable specific log levels and found that to be a nice interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why the user should have to work with two loggers. The consuming code should not care about logging targets.

Another issue is that your consuming code doesn't pass in the severity anywhere. Whenever you call a logging function you pass in the severity. The consuming code doesn't care what the current verbosity is, it just passes in a severity and relies on the implementation of the logger to know if the severity exceeds the verbosity level. (There is an exception to this rule, where you check against the verbosity level to avoid the overhead of creating the log message in high performance code)

I'd rather have one logger as the user, with two attached outputs, which might have a different verbosity level.

In the simplest case I'd create a global function `Logger& GetLogger()` which leads to user code like `GetLogger().LogDebug("New Object of Type .... created");`

First create an interface:

```
public class ILogger
{
  public:
    virtual LogDebug(string message)=0;
    ...
}
```

Then create one instance that supports subscription:

```
public class DispatchingLogger:ILogger
{
  private:
    vector<ILogger*> loggers;
  public:
    override LogDebug(string message)
    {
      foreach(ILogger logger in loggers)
      {
        logger.LogDebug(message);
      }
    }

    void Subscribe(ILogger* logger)
    {
      loggers.add(logger);
    }
}
```

Then the global `GetLogger()` function returns a single instance of `DispatchingLogger`. And you can subscribe several implementations with different verbosity levels to it. And user classes that implement `ILogger` can registered too.

*(I know my C++ syntax is incorrect, has been a bit since I worked with C++)*

Comment: Thanks for your post first. The reason of having two ore more loggers is that the user can define it´s own loggers. I only implemented Visual Studio, File or Stdout Appends so far. The user might derive from my Logger base class and add a TCP Logger for example. But I get your point too.

Comment: Having more than one logger implementation, and exposing only one logger instance to the consuming code are different issues. You can have both at the same time. In your example you subscribe the VS and the file logger to the broadcast events.

Comment: Thats almost the same implementatation that im currently using. I have a Logdispatch namespace with three functions: addLogger(), removeLogger() and logg(). addLogger() is called everytime a new Logger is instantiated and remove evertime a Logger is deleted. I´m using an intrusive list instead of an vector. Probably I will also think about policy based design later on but currently I want to get it working first.

Answer (score 0):

The verbosity level shows what messages (or rather, of what criticality) are to be logged.

E.g.

```
Set verbosity to INFO
Log a trace message  //the message will not be logged
Log a debug message  //the message will not be logged
Log an info message  //the message will be logged
Log a warning        //the message will be logged
Log an error or a fatal error.  // will be logged
```